# Как перемножить два дробных числа с кол-вом битов дробной части не кратных степеням двойки?

Tags: ассемблер, nasm, sasm

Всем привет!
Мне в одном проекте (NASM, x86, Intel 80386) нужно реализовать умножение и деление двух 64-битных чисел, которые лежат в стаке, в каждом из которых 14 нижних битов отведены под дробную часть, а оставшиеся 50 - целую.
Моя проблема заключается в том, что я не понимаю, как правильно перемножить дробную часть, не кратную степени 2, и целую.
Как мне это сделать лучше всего?

Answer (score 1):

Это просто числа с **фиксированной точкой** (в отличие от, например, double - с плавающей точкой).

Просто умножаете их как целые числа, получается 128-разрядный результат, в котором 28 младших бит относятся к "дробной части" (но Вам понадобится только 14 старших из них).

Таким образом, Вам нужно из числа, находящегося в двух регистрах (пара `RDX:RAX`), выделить 14 младших бит старшего регистра RDX, и 50 старших бит младшего регистра и объединить их (это как бы эквивалентно сдвигу 128-битного регистра вправо на 14 и взятию младшей части)

Набросок:

```
mov rax, num1
mul num2
shl rdx, 50
shr rax, 14
or rax, rdx
mov result, rax
```

Что происходит:

```
aaaa.bb * cccc.dd                       нужно выполнить
aaaabb * ccccdd =   qwerty uiasdf       умножение целых
                    ty0000 00uias       извлекаемые части
                           tyuias       объединение
                          tyui.as       интерпретация результата
```

---

как сделать умножение 64-разрядных чисел на 32-разрядной системе:

`M = 2^32`
Число `A = alo + M * ahi` состоит из двух 32-разрядных частей `(alo, ahi)`
Число `B = blo + M * bhi` состоит из двух 32-разрядных частей `(blo, bhi)`

Перемножим

```
A * B = (alo + M * ahi)*(blo + M * bhi) = 

        M*M*ahi*bhi + M*(alo*bhi+ahi*blo) + alo*blo
```

Таким образом, вычисляем произведение самых правых компонентов, получаем два 32-разрядных компонента (регистры eax, edx).

eax в dword результата, к edx добавляем младшую часть обоих произведений в скобках, получаем второй dword результата.

Старшие части обоих произведений в скобках добавляем к переносу от прошлых сложений, добавляем младшую часть первого произведения - получаем третий dword результата.

Остальное все собираем в четвертый dword.

Comment: в Intel 80386 нет 64битных регистров, в этом как раз и загвоздка

Comment: Ну сделайте 64x64=128 на 32-разрядных регистрах. Несколько громоздко, но реально.